# Keep Finder from opening when no other apps are open

Tags: macos, finder

I enabled being able to quit the Finder with

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool true; killall Finder
```

The problem is that the Finder opens automatically if no other program is open.

So for example let's say I only have Firefox open. If I close it, instead of being left with no open programs, I can see (from the Dock icon and from the `cmd - tab` menu) that the Finder is now open.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Why? Finder is meant to be always running. It is more than just the window manager for the desktop.

Comment: I don't use it for anything: my file manager is `lf` and my window manager is `yabai`. I get that macOS probably needs Finder for more than just managing files, but I should never have to interact with it if I don't want to.

Comment: You might try the post [How can I remove the Finder icon from my Dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/how-can-i-remove-the-finder-icon-from-my-dock?newreg=7853552a016a48d2a67c03406a1b7af9). To make it work you might need to disable System Integrity Protection.

Comment: Why? I don't want to remove its icon from the Dock (at least not now), I want it to stay closed.

Comment: He was probably meaning more along the lines of the thought to keep it out the `cmd - tab` programs menu as you mentioned.

Comment: Oh, so keeping it out of the Dock means that it will also disappear from the cmd-tab menu? Didn't know that, I'm gonna try it now.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but a good guess I suppose if nothing else. You are talking about two different things so maybe one will give you the other. The other answer indicates removing it entirely makes other things unstable so might as well make it disappear where you don't want it to be instead.

Comment: noibe, I came up with a solution; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now I tried it and I see what you mean. You're saying that after quitting the Finder, it remains not running until you've quit all other apps GUI apps (those that have an icon in the Dock). At that point, loginwindow.app (or possibly launchd) launches the Finder.

It turns out the solution is pretty easy. Just open Terminal, then quit the Finder, and run the following:

`launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist`

Quit all apps and the Finder should not be (re)launched.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was what you said in the update. I can keep the finder closed just fine as long as there's another app running, but when no other app is running the when the finder opens. It's like you can't be in a state with no apps running.

Comment: As I said yesterday, a running Finder is normal. It is supposed to be running. Having a Finder window open when you close other applications is another matter. Is that what you are saying, that when you close all apps, a Finder window appears? BTW, it's impossible to run a computer, Mac, Windows, Linux, what have you, with zero application/program open. Computers are meant to run programs, even if they work in the background, even third-parties you installed yourself.

Comment: @NSGod It works!! Thanks a lot, you made my life a lil bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Finder is an integral part of OS X or macOS. You can kill it, it'll restart, because it's not exactly the equivalent of Windows Explorer, it's needed by the OS to manage a host of other functions, indexation being one of them.

No Finder, no Spotlight, for example. No Time Machine either (for older versions). Finder is also in charge of virtual memory management.

My advice: leave Finder alone. It doesn't require a lot of ressources when no window is open, it works with reduced working set 99% of the time anyway, so no need to kill it, unless you want your machine to go unstable as all hell.

Comment: But it never restarts at random, it only does when no other app is open, and even without it everything seems to be working fine, including spotlight. But, if it's better to leave it open, is there at least a way to keep it out of the `cmd - tab` programs menu? That's the main reason I want it to stay closed, I often accidentally switch to it when I didn't mean to.

Comment: The core functionality of Spotlight (`mds`, `ms_stores`, `mdworker`) continue to work behind the scenes regardless of whether the Finder is running. The search menu item and Time Machine item in the upper right of the screen is part of the SystemUIServer process, not the Finder. Time Machine is part of Core Services and the `backupd` daemon continues to take care of backups regardless of whether the Finder is running. And no, the Finder is not in charge of virtual memory, the kernel is. While it may seem strange, it's entirely possible to not have the Finder running all the time.

Comment: You're globally right about the nuts-and-bolts of it, but Finder provides a UI for all those processes, especially mdworker, which has been known to be a CPU hog since its introduction in Tiger (under current form). I don't see an upside in not letting Finder run, unless it goes berserk on your CPU the way it used to in OS X 10.7. Shouldn't happen anymore. As for VM being solely controlled by the kernel, that's only partly true, because by default, macOS (or OS X) preempts all available disk space as potential VM, and relies on Finder and other processes to calculate the exact amount left.